# Showing this super easy example is a morphism of varieties using the harder definition

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Really easy question that I can't get my head around.

Let $X$ be a variety, and $x\in X$.

Why is $\psi:X\to X\times\{x\},\quad \psi:a\mapsto (a,x),$ a morphism of varieties?

I have the definition that $\psi$ is a morphism of varieties $\psi:X\to Y$ if there is an affine cover of $X$, $\{U_i\}$ and an affine cover of $Y$ by $\{V_i\}$, and the following properties:
$$\psi(U_i)\subset V_i$$
$$f\in O_Y(V_i)\implies f\circ \psi\in O_X(U_i)$$

---

So I guess for me $\psi: X\to X\times \{x\}$, where I can have an affine cover of $X$ by $U_i$. Then is my cover for $X\times \{x\}$ given by $V_i = U_i\times \{x\}$. Are these still open though? I guess I can think of $\{x\}\cong \Bbb A^0$, rather than thinking of it as a point of a variety, which would be closed but not open.

Then if that was the case, it is obvious that $\psi(U_i)=V_i$ and then after this, I can use the affine variety definition for morphisms for the latter condition.

Comment: please tell me how to improve my question

Comment: What is $a$? You do not specify what it is, which makes it impossible to understand what you're really asking.

Comment: @KReiser Sorry fixed

Comment: What is your definition of variety? If it is, say, that $X$ is a Zariski closed subset of a projective space (zero-set of some polynomials in $\mathbb{P}^n$) then $X \times \{x\} \subset \mathbb{P}^{2n+1}$. Say the coordinates on the first $\mathbb{P}^n$ were $y_i$, and on $\mathbb{P}^{2n+1}$ they are $y_i,z_j$. An open set $\{y_i\neq0\} \cap X$ corresponds to... $\{y_i \neq 0\} \cap (X \times \{x\})$.